# how I can change size at Title and subTitle of the QWizardPage?

Tags: python, title, subtitle, qwizardpage

For example in reference to the ClassPage1 I would change the self.setTitle("Choices") and       self.setSubTitle("Choose 1") the font and the size of the characters.
I don't know how it can be done. Some advice. Thank you

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
import sys

class IntroductionPage(QtWidgets.QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(IntroductionPage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setTitle("Introduction")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Welcome to the One Inc™'s Teacher Interactive Accessment tool. Follow the prompts to set up your Mark Sheet")
        self.label.setWordWrap(True)
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def nextId(self):
        return Wizard.class1

class ClassesPage1(QtWidgets.QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ClassesPage1, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setTitle("Choices")
        self.setSubTitle("Choose 1")

        self.radButton1 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('1A')
        self.radButton2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('1B')
        self.radButton3 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('1C')

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.radButton1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.radButton2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.radButton3)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def nextId(self):
        return Wizard.conclusion

class ConclusionPage(QtWidgets.QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ConclusionPage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label2)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

class Wizard(QtWidgets.QWizard):
    num_of_pages = 3
    (intro, class1,  conclusion) = range(num_of_pages)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Wizard, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setPage(self.intro, IntroductionPage(self))
        self.setPage(self.class1, ClassesPage1(self))
        self.setPage(self.conclusion, ConclusionPage(self))
        self.setStartId(self.intro)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    wizard = Wizard()

    wizard.setWindowTitle("Set Up")
    wizard.setWizardStyle(QtWidgets.QWizard.MacStyle)
    wizard.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I will increase the characters and the style for the Title and subTitle